# connection problem Hyperledger Composer on aws-ec2 and azure

Tags: azure, amazon-ec2, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have made 2 instances by following a tutorial [here](https://medium.com/1950labs/publish-a-business-network-in-multi-host-hyperledger-fabric-a5ad2015a487). One is made in azure and one is made at AWS. I have successfully bridge the connection on the docker instance. When I tried to

`composer network install --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --archiveFile stock-inquiry@0.0.1.bna`
at amazon side, I get

`composer network install --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --archiveFile stock-inquiry@0.0.1.bna
✖ Installing business network. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying install business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline
Command failed`

In azure side it works perfectly.

the logs at docker become like this

```html
2018-12-18 07:48:53.536 UTC [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 001 Starting peer:
 Version: 1.1.0
 Go version: go1.9.2
 OS/Arch: linux/amd64
 Experimental features: false
 Chaincode:
  Base Image Version: 0.4.6
  Base Docker Namespace: hyperledger
  Base Docker Label: org.hyperledger.fabric
  Docker Namespace: hyperledger

2018-12-18 07:48:53.537 UTC [ledgermgmt] initialize -> INFO 002 Initializing ledger mgmt
2018-12-18 07:48:53.538 UTC [kvledger] NewProvider -> INFO 003 Initializing ledger provider
2018-12-18 07:48:53.702 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> WARN 004 Retrying couchdb request in 125ms. Attempt:1  Error:Get http://couchdb:5984/: dial tcp 192.168.16.3:5984: getsockopt: connection refused
2018-12-18 07:48:53.828 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> WARN 005 Retrying couchdb request in 250ms. Attempt:2  Error:Get http://couchdb:5984/: dial tcp 192.168.16.3:5984: getsockopt: connection refused
2018-12-18 07:48:54.079 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> WARN 006 Retrying couchdb request in 500ms. Attempt:3  Error:Get http://couchdb:5984/: dial tcp 192.168.16.3:5984: getsockopt: connection refused
2018-12-18 07:48:54.580 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> WARN 007 Retrying couchdb request in 1s. Attempt:4  Error:Get http://couchdb:5984/: dial tcp 192.168.16.3:5984: getsockopt: connection refused
2018-12-18 07:48:55.581 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> WARN 008 Retrying couchdb request in 2s. Attempt:5  Error:Get http://couchdb:5984/: dial tcp 192.168.16.3:5984: getsockopt: connection refused
2018-12-18 07:48:57.680 UTC [couchdb] CreateDatabaseIfNotExist -> INFO 009 Created state database _users
2018-12-18 07:48:57.711 UTC [couchdb] CreateDatabaseIfNotExist -> INFO 00a Created state database _replicator
2018-12-18 07:48:57.733 UTC [couchdb] CreateDatabaseIfNotExist -> INFO 00b Created state database _global_changes
2018-12-18 07:48:57.741 UTC [kvledger] NewProvider -> INFO 00c ledger provider Initialized
2018-12-18 07:48:57.741 UTC [ledgermgmt] initialize -> INFO 00d ledger mgmt initialized
2018-12-18 07:48:57.741 UTC [peer] func1 -> INFO 00e Auto-detected peer address: 192.168.16.5:7051
2018-12-18 07:48:57.751 UTC [peer] func1 -> INFO 00f Returning peer0.org1.stock.com:7051
2018-12-18 07:48:57.751 UTC [peer] func1 -> INFO 010 Auto-detected peer address: 192.168.16.5:7051
2018-12-18 07:48:57.751 UTC [peer] func1 -> INFO 011 Returning peer0.org1.stock.com:7051
2018-12-18 07:48:57.760 UTC [nodeCmd] computeChaincodeEndpoint -> INFO 012 Entering computeChaincodeEndpoint with peerHostname: peer0.org1.stock.com
2018-12-18 07:48:57.760 UTC [nodeCmd] computeChaincodeEndpoint -> INFO 013 Exit with ccEndpoint: peer0.org1.stock.com:7052
2018-12-18 07:48:57.761 UTC [nodeCmd] createChaincodeServer -> WARN 014 peer.chaincodeListenAddress is not set, using peer0.org1.stock.com:7052
2018-12-18 07:48:57.761 UTC [eventhub_producer] start -> INFO 015 Event processor started
2018-12-18 07:48:57.762 UTC [chaincode] NewChaincodeSupport -> INFO 016 Chaincode support using peerAddress: peer0.org1.stock.com:7052
2018-12-18 07:48:57.763 UTC [sccapi] registerSysCC -> INFO 017 system chaincode cscc(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/cscc) registered
2018-12-18 07:48:57.763 UTC [sccapi] registerSysCC -> INFO 018 system chaincode lscc(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/lscc) registered
2018-12-18 07:48:57.763 UTC [sccapi] registerSysCC -> INFO 019 system chaincode escc(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/escc) registered
2018-12-18 07:48:57.764 UTC [sccapi] registerSysCC -> INFO 01a system chaincode vscc(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/vscc) registered
2018-12-18 07:48:57.764 UTC [sccapi] registerSysCC -> INFO 01b system chaincode qscc(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/qscc) registered
2018-12-18 07:48:57.765 UTC [gossip/service] func1 -> INFO 01c Initialize gossip with endpoint peer0.org1.stock.com:7051 and bootstrap set [127.0.0.1:7051]
2018-12-18 07:48:57.770 UTC [msp] DeserializeIdentity -> INFO 01d Obtaining identity
2018-12-18 07:48:57.773 UTC [gossip/discovery] NewDiscoveryService -> INFO 01e Started { [] [31 57 68 255 217 178 128 85 97 68 93 103 174 51 205 204 50 251 97 123 28 137 101 87 238 45 170 108 159 105 199 220] peer0.org1.stock.com:7051 <nil>} incTime is 1545119337773428448
2018-12-18 07:48:57.773 UTC [gossip/gossip] NewGossipService -> INFO 01f Creating gossip service with self membership of { [] [31 57 68 255 217 178 128 85 97 68 93 103 174 51 205 204 50 251 97 123 28 137 101 87 238 45 170 108 159 105 199 220] peer0.org1.stock.com:7051 <nil>}
2018-12-18 07:48:57.775 UTC [gossip/gossip] NewGossipService -> WARN 020 External endpoint is empty, peer will not be accessible outside of its organization
2018-12-18 07:48:57.778 UTC [gossip/gossip] start -> INFO 021 Gossip instance peer0.org1.stock.com:7051 started
2018-12-18 07:48:57.782 UTC [cscc] Init -> INFO 022 Init CSCC
2018-12-18 07:48:57.782 UTC [sccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 023 system chaincode cscc/(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/cscc) deployed
2018-12-18 07:48:57.783 UTC [sccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 024 system chaincode lscc/(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/lscc) deployed
2018-12-18 07:48:57.783 UTC [escc] Init -> INFO 025 Successfully initialized ESCC
2018-12-18 07:48:57.783 UTC [sccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 026 system chaincode escc/(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/escc) deployed
2018-12-18 07:48:57.784 UTC [sccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 027 system chaincode vscc/(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/vscc) deployed
2018-12-18 07:48:57.784 UTC [qscc] Init -> INFO 028 Init QSCC
2018-12-18 07:48:57.784 UTC [sccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 029 system chaincode qscc/(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/qscc) deployed
2018-12-18 07:48:57.784 UTC [nodeCmd] initSysCCs -> INFO 02a Deployed system chaincodes
2018-12-18 07:48:57.785 UTC [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 02b Starting peer with ID=[name:"peer0.org1.stock.com" ], network ID=[dev], address=[peer0.org1.stock.com:7051]
2018-12-18 07:48:57.786 UTC [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 02c Started peer with ID=[name:"peer0.org1.stock.com" ], network ID=[dev], address=[peer0.org1.stock.com:7051]
2018-12-18 07:49:04.193 UTC [ledgermgmt] CreateLedger -> INFO 02d Creating ledger [mychannel] with genesis block
2018-12-18 07:49:04.195 UTC [fsblkstorage] newBlockfileMgr -> INFO 02e Getting block information from block storage
2018-12-18 07:49:04.237 UTC [couchdb] CreateDatabaseIfNotExist -> INFO 02f Created state database mychannel_
2018-12-18 07:49:04.278 UTC [kvledger] CommitWithPvtData -> INFO 030 Channel [mychannel]: Committed block [0] with 1 transaction(s)
2018-12-18 07:49:04.334 UTC [ledgermgmt] CreateLedger -> INFO 031 Created ledger [mychannel] with genesis block
2018-12-18 07:49:04.373 UTC [cscc] Init -> INFO 032 Init CSCC
2018-12-18 07:49:04.373 UTC [sccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 033 system chaincode cscc/mychannel(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/cscc) deployed
2018-12-18 07:49:04.374 UTC [sccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 034 system chaincode lscc/mychannel(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/lscc) deployed
2018-12-18 07:49:04.374 UTC [escc] Init -> INFO 035 Successfully initialized ESCC
2018-12-18 07:49:04.374 UTC [sccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 036 system chaincode escc/mychannel(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/escc) deployed
2018-12-18 07:49:04.374 UTC [sccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 037 system chaincode vscc/mychannel(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/vscc) deployed
2018-12-18 07:49:04.374 UTC [qscc] Init -> INFO 038 Init QSCC
2018-12-18 07:49:04.375 UTC [sccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 039 system chaincode qscc/mychannel(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/qscc) deployed
2018-12-18 07:59:56.451 UTC [couchdb] CreateDatabaseIfNotExist -> INFO 03a Created state database mychannel_lscc
2018-12-18 07:59:56.457 UTC [lscc] executeInstall -> INFO 03b Installed Chaincode [stock-inquiry] Version [0.0.1] to peer
2018-12-18 08:01:31.970 UTC [endorser] ProcessProposal -> ERRO 03c [mychannel][d8bef524] simulateProposal() resulted in chaincode name:"lscc"  response status 500 for txid: d8bef524455b7411da3b169efdf232bf50b8f17a7a7ddb3b4acd25ee413e8ae7
2018-12-18 08:02:45.646 UTC [couchdb] CreateDatabaseIfNotExist -> INFO 03d Created state database mychannel_stock-inquiry
2018-12-18 08:02:45.657 UTC [cceventmgmt] HandleStateUpdates -> INFO 03e Channel [mychannel]: Handling LSCC state update for chaincode [stock-inquiry]
2018-12-18 08:02:45.682 UTC [couchdb] CreateIndex -> INFO 03f Created CouchDB index [selectCommoditiesByOwner] in state database [mychannel_stock-inquiry] using design document [_design/selectCommoditiesByOwnerDoc]
2018-12-18 08:02:45.685 UTC [couchdb] CreateIndex -> INFO 040 Created CouchDB index [selectCommoditiesByProductName] in state database [mychannel_stock-inquiry] using design document [_design/selectCommoditiesByProductNameDoc]
2018-12-18 08:02:45.687 UTC [couchdb] CreateIndex -> INFO 041 Created CouchDB index [selectCommodities] in state database [mychannel_stock-inquiry] using design document [_design/selectCommoditiesDoc]
2018-12-18 08:02:45.690 UTC [couchdb] CreateIndex -> INFO 042 Created CouchDB index [selectCommoditiesWithHighQuantity] in state database [mychannel_stock-inquiry] using design document [_design/selectCommoditiesWithHighQuantityDoc]
2018-12-18 08:02:45.722 UTC [kvledger] CommitWithPvtData -> INFO 043 Channel [mychannel]: Committed block [1] with 1 transaction(s)
2018-12-18 08:02:45.763 UTC [common/deliver] deliverBlocks -> WARN 044 [channel: mychannel] Error sending to 40.74.88.202:38350: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = the stream has been done
```

Then I continue to develop at azure side hoping to import the business card from azure side to amazon side, maybe then it will work perfectly. So I start creating a new business card and send it to amazon side. after I import the card and try to ping the business card, It gives me this message

```
    Error: Error trying login and get user Context. Error: Error trying to enroll user. Error: Calling enrollment endpoint failed with error [Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 52.193.188.33:7054]
Command failed
```

They cannot ping each other because I haven't enabled ICMP at azure side. I have opened the ports so they can communicate each other.
inbound port settings for amazon side looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mMoV.png). Azure side looks almost the same, just differs at 7000 to 7100 become 8000 to 8100.
What should I do to install the business card? I am sure that the port is opened for each other to see.

Edit 1:
docker exec log at the start for azure side

```html
# Create the channel
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.stock.com/msp" peer0.org1.stock.com peer channel create -o orderer.stock.com:7050 -c mychannel -f /etc/hyperledger/configtx/channel.tx
2018-12-19 00:41:47.014 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
2018-12-19 00:41:47.079 UTC [main] main -> INFO 002 Exiting.....
# Join peer0.org1.stock.com to the channel.
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.stock.com/msp" peer0.org1.stock.com peer channel join -b mychannel.block
2018-12-19 00:41:47.352 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
2018-12-19 00:41:47.562 UTC [channelCmd] executeJoin -> INFO 002 Successfully submitted proposal to join channel
2018-12-19 00:41:47.562 UTC [main] main -> INFO 003 Exiting.....
```

docker exec log at amazon side

```html
# Create the channel
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.stock.com/msp" peer1.org1.stock.com peer channel fetch config -o orderer.stock.com:7050 -c mychannel
2018-12-19 00:42:11.228 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
2018-12-19 00:42:11.254 UTC [cli.common] readBlock -> INFO 002 Received block: 0
2018-12-19 00:42:11.269 UTC [cli.common] readBlock -> INFO 003 Received block: 0
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.stock.com/msp" peer1.org1.stock.com peer channel join -b mychannel_config.block
2018-12-19 00:42:11.531 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
2018-12-19 00:42:11.748 UTC [channelCmd] executeJoin -> INFO 002 Successfully submitted proposal to join channel
```

edit 3: if I want to install bna file at amazon side, it cannot be done.
it will give me this error

```html
✖ Installing business network. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying install business network. Error: The business network failed to install on 1 or more peers: Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline
Command failed
```

On the other hand, if I install on azure side., I get error LSCC at azure side, but it will gives me a succeed message

```html
2018-12-27 05:16:46.972 UTC [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 001 Starting peer:
 Version: 1.2.0
 Commit SHA: cae2ad4
 Go version: go1.10
 OS/Arch: linux/amd64
 Experimental features: false
 Chaincode:
  Base Image Version: 0.4.10
  Base Docker Namespace: hyperledger
  Base Docker Label: org.hyperledger.fabric
  Docker Namespace: hyperledger

2018-12-27 05:16:46.972 UTC [ledgermgmt] initialize -> INFO 002 Initializing ledger mgmt
2018-12-27 05:16:46.972 UTC [kvledger] NewProvider -> INFO 003 Initializing ledger provider
2018-12-27 05:16:47.114 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> WARN 004 Retrying couchdb request in 125ms. Attempt:1  Error:Get http://couchdb1:5984/: dial tcp 172.25.0.2:5984: connect: connection refused
2018-12-27 05:16:47.241 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> WARN 005 Retrying couchdb request in 250ms. Attempt:2  Error:Get http://couchdb1:5984/: dial tcp 172.25.0.2:5984: connect: connection refused
2018-12-27 05:16:47.492 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> WARN 006 Retrying couchdb request in 500ms. Attempt:3  Error:Get http://couchdb1:5984/: dial tcp 172.25.0.2:5984: connect: connection refused
2018-12-27 05:16:47.994 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> WARN 007 Retrying couchdb request in 1s. Attempt:4  Error:Get http://couchdb1:5984/: dial tcp 172.25.0.2:5984: connect: connection refused
2018-12-27 05:16:49.163 UTC [couchdb] CreateDatabaseIfNotExist -> INFO 008 Created state database _users
2018-12-27 05:16:49.203 UTC [couchdb] CreateDatabaseIfNotExist -> INFO 009 Created state database _replicator
2018-12-27 05:16:49.269 UTC [couchdb] CreateDatabaseIfNotExist -> INFO 00a Created state database _global_changes
2018-12-27 05:16:49.344 UTC [kvledger] NewProvider -> INFO 00b ledger provider Initialized
2018-12-27 05:16:49.344 UTC [ledgermgmt] initialize -> INFO 00c ledger mgmt initialized
2018-12-27 05:16:49.344 UTC [peer] func1 -> INFO 00d Auto-detected peer address: 172.25.0.3:7051
2018-12-27 05:16:49.344 UTC [peer] func1 -> INFO 00e Returning peer1.org1.example.com:7051
2018-12-27 05:16:49.345 UTC [peer] func1 -> INFO 00f Auto-detected peer address: 172.25.0.3:7051
2018-12-27 05:16:49.345 UTC [peer] func1 -> INFO 010 Returning peer1.org1.example.com:7051
2018-12-27 05:16:49.346 UTC [eventhub_producer] start -> INFO 011 Event processor started
2018-12-27 05:16:49.347 UTC [nodeCmd] computeChaincodeEndpoint -> INFO 012 Entering computeChaincodeEndpoint with peerHostname: peer1.org1.example.com
2018-12-27 05:16:49.347 UTC [nodeCmd] computeChaincodeEndpoint -> INFO 013 Exit with ccEndpoint: peer1.org1.example.com:7052
2018-12-27 05:16:49.348 UTC [nodeCmd] createChaincodeServer -> WARN 014 peer.chaincodeListenAddress is not set, using peer1.org1.example.com:7052
2018-12-27 05:16:49.349 UTC [sccapi] registerSysCC -> INFO 015 system chaincode cscc(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/cscc) registered
2018-12-27 05:16:49.349 UTC [sccapi] registerSysCC -> INFO 016 system chaincode lscc(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/lscc) registered
2018-12-27 05:16:49.349 UTC [sccapi] registerSysCC -> INFO 017 system chaincode qscc(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/qscc) registered
2018-12-27 05:16:49.354 UTC [gossip/gossip] NewGossipService -> INFO 018 Creating gossip service with self membership of { [] [211 55 188 245 219 253 179 85 254 143 15 136 54 239 192 58 60 153 254 80 243 208 48 137 183 237 162 71 84 184 182 206] peer1.org1.example.com:7051 <nil> <nil>}
2018-12-27 05:16:49.355 UTC [gossip/gossip] NewGossipService -> WARN 019 External endpoint is empty, peer will not be accessible outside of its organization
2018-12-27 05:16:49.355 UTC [gossip/gossip] start -> INFO 01a Gossip instance peer1.org1.example.com:7051 started
2018-12-27 05:16:49.356 UTC [cscc] Init -> INFO 01b Init CSCC
2018-12-27 05:16:49.356 UTC [sccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 01c system chaincode cscc/(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/cscc) deployed
2018-12-27 05:16:49.357 UTC [sccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 01d system chaincode lscc/(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/lscc) deployed
2018-12-27 05:16:49.357 UTC [qscc] Init -> INFO 01e Init QSCC
2018-12-27 05:16:49.357 UTC [sccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 01f system chaincode qscc/(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/qscc) deployed
2018-12-27 05:16:49.357 UTC [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 020 Deployed system chaincodes
2018-12-27 05:16:49.358 UTC [discovery] NewService -> INFO 021 Created with config TLS: false, authCacheMaxSize: 1000, authCachePurgeRatio: 0.750000
2018-12-27 05:16:49.358 UTC [nodeCmd] registerDiscoveryService -> INFO 022 Discovery service activated
2018-12-27 05:16:49.358 UTC [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 023 Starting peer with ID=[name:"peer1.org1.example.com" ], network ID=[dev], address=[peer1.org1.example.com:7051]
2018-12-27 05:16:49.359 UTC [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 024 Started peer with ID=[name:"peer1.org1.example.com" ], network ID=[dev], address=[peer1.org1.example.com:7051]
2018-12-27 05:16:57.465 UTC [ledgermgmt] CreateLedger -> INFO 025 Creating ledger [mychannel] with genesis block
2018-12-27 05:16:57.478 UTC [fsblkstorage] newBlockfileMgr -> INFO 026 Getting block information from block storage
2018-12-27 05:16:57.533 UTC [couchdb] CreateDatabaseIfNotExist -> INFO 027 Created state database mychannel_
2018-12-27 05:16:57.564 UTC [kvledger] CommitWithPvtData -> INFO 028 Channel [mychannel]: Committed block [0] with 1 transaction(s)
2018-12-27 05:16:57.564 UTC [pvtdatastorage] func1 -> INFO 029 Purger started: Purging expired private data till block number [0]
2018-12-27 05:16:57.565 UTC [pvtdatastorage] func1 -> INFO 02a Purger finished
2018-12-27 05:16:57.615 UTC [ledgermgmt] CreateLedger -> INFO 02b Created ledger [mychannel] with genesis block
2018-12-27 05:16:57.654 UTC [cscc] Init -> INFO 02c Init CSCC
2018-12-27 05:16:57.654 UTC [sccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 02d system chaincode cscc/mychannel(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/cscc) deployed
2018-12-27 05:16:57.654 UTC [sccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 02e system chaincode lscc/mychannel(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/lscc) deployed
2018-12-27 05:16:57.655 UTC [qscc] Init -> INFO 02f Init QSCC
2018-12-27 05:16:57.655 UTC [sccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 030 system chaincode qscc/mychannel(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/qscc) deployed
2018-12-27 05:17:03.656 UTC [gossip/election] beLeader -> INFO 031 [211 55 188 245 219 253 179 85 254 143 15 136 54 239 192 58 60 153 254 80 243 208 48 137 183 237 162 71 84 184 182 206] : Becoming a leader
2018-12-27 05:18:54.408 UTC [couchdb] CreateDatabaseIfNotExist -> INFO 032 Created state database mychannel_lscc
2018-12-27 05:18:54.413 UTC [lscc] executeInstall -> INFO 033 Installed Chaincode [stock-inquiry] Version [0.0.2] to peer
2018-12-27 05:19:12.469 UTC [endorser] ProcessProposal -> ERRO 034 [][c4b74ceb] simulateProposal() resulted in chaincode name:"lscc"  response status 500 for txid: c4b74cebeae32b1584387b0b12398c880a928723a8d200c205f3c96eff3e9dfc
```

Comment: This is a network addressing/connectivity error - I would suggest using the `nc` command to test connectivity between the 2 environments (e.g. `nc -d <peer> 7051` ) and then try using `wget` "inside" the containers to prove they can see eachother.

Perhaps trying the whole activity inside a single environment first to prove the steps and see what the successful logs look like would be a good exercise too.

Comment: nc -v 52.193.188.33 7054
Connection to 52.193.188.33 7054 port [tcp/*] succeeded!

if I use this on azure, I can see they are connected to each other

Comment: The only difference is see is when I try to start peering the docker, I can see one being a leader and one does not. When I tried it locally with only physical machines, they both become leader. But I think I put the same settings on either of them. only changed the ip settings.

Comment: Have you used `docker exec` to get "inside" the containers, and verified that the orderer can see both peers and that both the peers can see the orderer and eachother?

Comment: added the log when for the docker exec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem fixed, amazon side cannot see himself. I need to open his own port connection to be seen by himself.